# categories Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: category

when i enable or do any change in (admin -> catalog -> categories )

i found this message

**Type Error occurred when creating object: ZzDbdc\Catalog\Rewrite\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor**

, so what i have to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably modified this controller construct which means you have to compile it again.

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
``` bin/magento setup:di:compile``bin/magento cache:flush ```

Comment: i did this commands but still had a problem